# CRM 2011 Dialog with Dynamic Advanced Find

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have written a Dialog that uses an Advanced Find where the user types in part of a search term, i.e., similar to:

[Dialog’s Query Step: Demystifying the Advanced Mode Capabilities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/01/28/dialog-s-query-step-demystifying-the-advanced-mode-capabilities.aspx).

In my case I created one to find all the Contacts in a post code area starting with "xyz..."

It works fine and I get the contacts in a picklist. How can I get this in a grid of results like you can for a regular advanced find? As I understand it the Query CRM data operation only gives you radio buttons or a list as output types. But is there some ingenious way of grabbing the results perhaps via a child workflow and writing them to a grid?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you're looking for something a little more out of the box, but one approach would be to use an HTML web resource.  You can mimic the dialog look and feel by using the CRM 2011 Style Guide included in the SDK (in the sdk\resources\styleguide folder).

Answer (score 0):

I think this cant be done out of the box. You can of course create a webresource and then  embed the advanced find view using fetchxml query.

Please take a  look at the following url. Hope it helps.

http://crmentropy.blogspot.com/2009/11/embedding-advanced-find-views-in-entity.html